# Is there anything similar to AWTListener in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I am looking for a way by which I can capture all events (specifically keyboard/mouse events) in a JavaFX application. Is there anything similar to AWTListener in JavaFX? In Java, by creating a AWTListener and adding it to default toolkit I can capture all the events.

**Adding some background**

I am involved with Marathon, a test automation tool for Java/Swing applications, and currently in the process of evaluating how complicated it is to add JavaFX support. By design, I do not have access to the JavaFX application itself. For Java/Swing we use javaagent to load Marathon hook into the AUT and use AWTListener to listen for all events. I suspect that something similar should be possible for JavaFX.

Comment: Take a look at the event capture feature on the [ScenicView tool](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), perhaps it's similar to what you want.  I don't know how it works though, or the source code for it.  You could ask the ScenicView developers.  Even if the way ScenicView handles it isn't exactly what you want to do, the developers will probably know a good way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Had a look at scenic view and tried to get in touch with the developers without success. A thread on java.net forums gave some information, but that doesn't help. Currently, I am thinking of using java agent instrumentation to  add handlers whenever a node is constructed. I shall post my findings here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how exactly your goal can be achieved, but I would start by taking a look at the `EventDispatcher` of a `Scene`.

```
final EventDispatcher eventDispatcher = scene.getEventDispatcher();
scene.setEventDispatcher( new EventDispatcher()
{
    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent( final Event event, final EventDispatchChain tail )
    {
        System.out.println( "Dispatching event [" + event + "]." );
        return eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent( event, tail );
    }
} );
```